# Label width not grown according to content of label

Tags: swift, xcode

[label width is not increasing according to content in table view cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqeda.png)

[Please check the attached image for detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBTnJ.png)

Comment: Share the screenshot of the constraints you have applied

Answer (score 0):

Make constraint >= 20(some constant) to Safe Area and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks,the problem is the my  logic is worked in my  project ,but when i used same logic in another project it won't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to put below constraints to the UILabel instead of leading Constraints.

[image]

**Why this happens so ?**

As the `leading` is not defined flexible, It will choose the `constant` value and therefore  it will by default will leave space equal or greater from leading.

If we set leading with safe area it will increase width as the text expand till it reaches the safe area line.

Hope this works !!!!